# React native http request stops once app goes to background

Tags: ios, react-native

Scenario:

1. User clicks on a button that invokes a fetch action that takes up to 60 seconds to respond - once the server the responds a set of other actions are invoked.
2. The user minimize the application during the fetch request.
3. The user returns to the application.

Expected behavior:

1. The app should continue its process from the point it stopped.

What happens:

1. The process just stops and the action set is not invoked

How is it possible to continue the action set in the background ?

Comment: you have to tell in app that you want to download something in background.  Check this - https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: is there way to use the "setting up a finte-length task" with objective-c ?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164897/ios-executing-a-finite-length-task-in-the-background and https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/finite-length-tasks-in-background-ios-swift-60f2db4fa01b#:~:text=Apples%20recommended%20way%20of%20performing,background%20during%20the%20task's%20execution. . use both references.